# Making xslt between two schemas in MapForce

Tags: xml, xslt, xsd, mapping, map-force

I need to map two schemas in order to get xslt file. Main element in my target schema is CadastreFeatureCollection who contains only one CadastreFeatureCollectionMembers element. In that element I have about 70 other elements. Now, I have two problems:

1. My transformed gml need to be like this:

   `<CadastreFeatureCollection>
      <CadastreFeatureCollectionMember>
        <State>
        <Country>
        <City>
        <Village>
        <...>`

But MapForce makes it like this:

```
`<CadastreFeatureCollection>
   <CadastreFeatureCollectionMember>
     <State>
   </CadastreFeatureCollectionMember>
   <CadastreFeatureCollectionMember>
     <Country>
   </CadastreFeatureCollectionMember>....`
```

What I am missing? I choose CadastreFeatureCollection as root element.

2.MapForce moves features in schema and they are not in the same order as need to be. How this is possible?

P.S. I use FME to get first xsd/gml from SQLServer database, and then MapForce to get transformation file for making final gml valid with my needed schema.

EDIT: I think that if I succeed in resolving first problem, the other will be solved for itself because in every feature member is just one feature, so MapForce reorders feature members in feature collection, not features themselves.

Comment: Neither the actual nor the desired XML is valid. Is this intentional?

Comment: I just wrote an example (for representing the situation, this is not a real code). Schemas are valid.

Comment: can you provide the XML toy are trying to translate? I suspect that elements have namepsaces you are not aware of.